# Как обновить свойства заказа через rest api? Битрикс24

Tags: веб-программирование, api, битрикс, rest, битрикс24

Пробую как в примере но не канает. Ошибки никакой не дает, но и значение он не обновляет.

/rest/sale.order.update

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "fields": {
        "comments": "Test Comment",
        "statusId": "N",
        "properties": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "orderPropsId": "1",
                "value": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой как у меня, решайте через метод

/rest/sale.propertyvalue.modify

```
{
    "fields": {
        "order": {
            "id":"1",
            "propertyValues": [
                {
                    "orderPropsId": "1",
                    "value": "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```